# Drupal services API returns "access denied for user anonymous" with xcode basic auth

Tags: swift, xcode, api, drupal

I have basic auth setup and working with `Drupal services`, and am using the administrator login. It is returning data for a voting API. When I access the site (with login) it retrieves the details.  But on my xcode project, when I query the API as a get command (using services definition http://example.site/ios1/user/{UID} ) it returns following error.

> "access denied for user anonymous".

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.  I had to select 'http basic authentication' in Drupal services, add 'headers' to the alamofire query, plus my authentication header needed to e:

```
    let user = "example"
    let password = "example"
    let credentialData = "\(user):\(password)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
    let headers = ["Authorization": "Basic \(base64Credentials)"]
```